# How to resolve is_selected() not returning True even if the checkbox is selected?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, webdriver

I'm using Selenium + python to check the status of a checkbox but it always returns False.

Checkbox HTML
[image: Checkbox HTML]

I'm using XPath

```
value = "//span[@title='Select Physical']"
```

I'm using the code below to evaluate if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value).is_selected():
    self.click_button_by_xpath(value)
```

Not sure what I'm I missing here.

Comment: can you share url?

Comment: you may or may have not noticed that the check box element is actually a `<span>`, which would affect what you can test on it, the method you mention in the title may only work on real checkboxes

Comment: @Wonka cannot share url, its a local ip address.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_selected()` only works on a checkbox or radio button according to [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.is_selected).

Without being able to see the other relevant HTML, I'm assuming that the `aria-checked="true"` attribute indicates whether the checkbox is checked. Assuming that's true, the code below should work.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value)
if button.get_attribute("aria-checked") == "true":
    button.click()
```